# Mono console app on Mac: how to read/alter from ~/Library files on MacOS Mojave

Tags: mono, access-control, visual-studio-mac, macos-mojave

Trying to migrate my mono console app to the latest MacOS (Mojave, 10.14). Unfortunately, it seems like operations to read or alter files in ~/Library are locked down.

I know you can add specific apps "Full Disk Access" in Security / Privacy settings, but having added the mono executable there, it still gives me a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` when my app runs and it attempts to call `File.Exists` and `File.Delete`. I've tried this both via Visual Studio for Mac Debug mode, and by manually running the debug output from Terminal.

Comment: what do you mean with mono executable here? beware you might have targeted a symlink

Comment: I am using `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/bin/mono-sgen64` as the executable.

Comment: @knocte you definitely lead me down the right path. Instead of mono, the app I needed to add in Full Disk Access was `terminal`.